# Unable to compile css with Aurora

Tags: theming

compass watch

> > > Change detected at 02:13:25 to: style.scss
> > >           error sass/style.scss (Line 20 of sass/partials/global/_base.scss: File to import not found or unreadable: aurora/susy-grid.
> > >       Load paths:
> > >         /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/txmo/sites/all/themes/txmo_aurora/sass
> > >         /Users/davidfells/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
> > >         /Users/davidfells/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
> > >         Compass::SpriteImporter)

Running Ruby 1.9.3, latest versions of all gems freshly installed with JewelryBox. Other users on dev team are able to build this with matching gem versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the "aurora" gem cannot be installed alongside compass & compass-aurora for all this to work properly.